# React app vite deployin on vercel and it failed

Tags: reactjs, npm, deployment, vite, vercel

I was deployin the vite project on vercel and I have also run the "npm run build" before that and it works fine but when in vercel deployment it failed and these are the error code-

Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
Cloning github.com/yourRichard/RapidQuest (Branch: master, Commit: b3a7b4d)
Previous build cache not available
Cloning completed: 374.164ms
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 33.1.0
Installing dependencies...
added 499 packages in 14s
132 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details
Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+
Running "npm run build"

> rapidquest@0.0.0 build
> vite build
> vite v5.0.11 building for production...
> transforming...
> ✓ 29 modules transformed.
> Could not resolve "./dashboard" from "src/scenes/index.js"
> file: /vercel/path0/src/scenes/index.js
> error during build:
> RollupError: Could not resolve "./dashboard" from "src/scenes/index.js"
> at error (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:337:30)
> at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18000:24)
> at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:17960:26
> Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

At first the "dashboard" folder was importing from scence folder so I changed the path to index.js but it still didnt work...